# Select join two tables and loop to get two different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to query the RELATIONS table (WHERE between two dates) and get the ENTITY_ID related of each SOURCE/ACCOUNT pairs in the RELATIONS table.

```
- ENTITIES table
ENTITY_ID (PK)
ENTITY_NAME

    - ACCOUNTS table
    SOURCE    (PK)
    ACCOUNT   (PK)
    ENTITY_ID (FK)

        - RELATIONS table
        RELATION_ID (PK)
        SOURCE_1    (FK)
        ACCOUNT_1   (FK)
        SOURCE_2    (FK)
        ACCOUNT_2   (FK)
        TIMESTAMP
```

Is there a way to do this in one query?

Output of query should look like this:

```
RELATION_ID
SOURCE_1
ACCOUNT_1
ENTITY_ID_1 (ENTITY_ID (from ACCOUNTS table) related to SOURCE_1 and ACCOUNT_1)
SOURCE_2
ACCOUNT_2
ENTITY_ID_2 (ENTITY_ID (from ACCOUNTS table) related to SOURCE_2 and ACCOUNT_2)
```

I have an idea on how to get ENTITY_ID_1, but not sure how to get ENTITY_ID_2 at the same time.

```
SELECT
     R.RELATION_ID
    ,R.SOURCE_1
    ,R.ACCOUNT_1
    ,A.ENTITY_ID AS ENTITY_ID_1 
    ,R.SOURCE_2
    ,R.ACCOUNT_2
FROM RELATIONS R
JOIN ACCOUNTS A
  ON R.SOURCE_1  = A.SOURCE
 AND R.ACCOUNT_1 = A.ACCOUNT
WHERE R.TIMESTAMP >= DATETIME1 AND R.TIMESTAMP < DATETIME2
```

Any thoughts on a better title for this question is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need two `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT R.RELATION_ID, R.SOURCE_1, R.ACCOUNT_1,
       A1.ENTITY_ID AS ENTITY_ID_1, 
       A2.ENTITY_ID AS ENTITY_ID_2, 
       R.SOURCE_2, R.ACCOUNT_2
FROM RELATIONS R JOIN
     ACCOUNTS A1
     ON R.SOURCE_1  = A1.SOURCE AND
        R.ACCOUNT_1 = A1.ACCOUNT JOIN
     ACCOUNT A2
     ON R.SOURCE_2  = A2.SOURCE AND
        R.ACCOUNT_2 = A2.ACCOUNT
WHERE R.TIMESTAMP >= DATETIME1 AND
      R.TIMESTAMP < DATETIME2
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, just ordered your book